# php string formating in javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, html

Please help me to solve this string formating . it shows error while running.

I need to call a java script function AddHotel() with some php variables from an input tag. while running the first parameter in function shows error. It should be like  onClick='AddHotel('divid', 'some_id', 'id',ids,rate)'

but while running in comes as `onClick='AddHotel(divid', 'some_id', 'id',ids,rate)'`

```
$resort[] = "<div id='".$iiiddd."'><input id='hotel_day".$child_post->ID.$dyid."' name='hotel_day".$dyid."' type='radio' value='".$child_post->ID."' onclick='AddHotel(".$p.",'".$s."','".$psid."','".$dyid."','".$child_post->ID."',".$child_post->fields['price'].")' />
<input id='".$s."' name='expsel".$dyid."[]' type='hidden' value='' />".$child_post->post_title."<span>Rs:- ".$child_post->fields['price']."</span></div>";
```

Comment: Check properly you are missing Quotes, It can be spotted easily.

Comment: What this snippet really lacks is a couple of mysql queries.

Answer (score -1):

You want to escape Quotes

```
$resort[] = "<div id='".$iiiddd."'><input id='hotel_day".$child_post->ID.$dyid."' name='hotel_day".$dyid."' type='radio' value='".$child_post->ID."' onclick='AddHotel(".$p.",\'".$s."\',\'".$psid."\',\'".$dyid."\',\'".$child_post->ID."\',".$child_post->fields['price'].")' />".$child_post->post_title."Rs:- ".$child_post->fields['price']."";
```

Answer (score -1):

***For all who face such issues:***

You should **always** use Double quotes for HTML attributes value eg:

```
<div attribute="value"><div>
```

For passing **variables** in a Javascript functions, you must use **quotes** (single quote preferably) for string. eg:

```
somethingAwesome('work', 'life', 1);
```

While embedding HTML and Javascript in PHP, you must not get confused with Quotes.

PHP string + HTML element:

```
$string = '<div></div>';
```

PHP string + HTML element with attributes:

```
$string = '<div id="awesome"></div>';
```

PHP string + HTML element with attributes + Javascript Function:

```
$string = '<div id="awesome" onclick="somethingAwesome()"></div>';
```

PHP string + HTML element with attributes + Javascript Function with Parameters:

```
$string = '<div id="awesome" onclick="somethingAwesome(\''.$string.'\', \''.$string2.'\', '.$integer.');"></div>';
```

You are open to choose double or single quotes, but **following one particular fashion** will prevent you from getting confused.

Also remember to **Indent** your code even in case of HTML in strings

Solution for your issue:

```
$resort[] = '<div id="'.$iiiddd.'">
                <input id="hotel_day'.$child_post->ID.$dyid.'" name="hotel_day'.$dyid.'" type="radio" value="'.$child_post->ID.'" onclick="AddHotel(\''.$p.'\', \''.$s.'\', '.$psid.', \''.$dyid.'\', '.$child_post->ID.', \''.$child_post->fields['price'].'\')" />
                <input id="'.$s.'" name="expsel'.$dyid.'[]" type="hidden" value="" />
                '.$child_post->post_title.'
                <span>Rs:- '.$child_post->fields['price'].'</span>
            </div>';
```